# I want to filter line and give me third part (data) what do i do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Below is my code, I have a file that its data is such:

```
Recibido(IP/Size/Data): 192.168.4.3 / 39 / 191772,3.81,13.67,3.43,-19,-1664,-270
```

To filter line and give me third part (data) what do I do?

```
with open('c:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/file/capture(1).txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        a = line
        data = a.split('/')[-1].strip()
        data = list(map(float, data.split(',')))
        print(data)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\hadi.py", line 5, in <module>
    data = list(map(float, data.split(',')))
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> a = 'Recibido(IP/Size/Data): 192.168.4.3 / 42 / 344127,109.24,-148.14,135.78,293,837,541'
>>> data = a.split('/')[-1].strip()
>>> data
'344127,109.24,-148.14,135.78,293,837,541'
>>> data = list(map(float, data.split(',')))
>>> data
[344127.0, 109.24, -148.14, 135.78, 293.0, 837.0, 541.0]
```

Comment: if(a) is one of the lines of my data file and if i want make all lines like a and put them to list what do i do

Comment: `with open('file.txt', 'r') as f: for line in f: a = line; ...`  
@amin Iterate over the lines of the file and perform this operation for all lines.

Comment: your code have this error :                                                                          Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/hadi.py", line 5, in <module>
    data = list(map(float, data.split(',')))
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: Please edit the question with the actual data of the file. Otherwise it's difficult to write code without knowing what kind of input data gets fed into the code.

Comment: i edit that @Diptangsu

Comment: Please format your question properly and copy paste the contents of the file.